# Unable to delete custom post types, confusion around capabilities

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, capabilities

So I'm working on a plugin for creating a questions/answers system that's as simple and well-integrated as possible (not unlike this site) but am stuck at the creation of the custom post types.

You can see my current code here: http://pastebin.com/MXjPVuPQ

The key is in allowing all users (down to "subscribers") to post questions and answers, edit their own posts, etc., whilst admins can manage and moderate these. So following [a tutorial](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types), I've got the basics going. Subscribers can create their own questions and answers and edit their own, but not others'.

However, these can't be deleted. Using the "Members" plugin I've given the appropriate capabilities (reference?) but not even an admin can delete their own or others' posts. I'm not really sure why this is happening, any obvious hints or something I'm missing?